# MySQL query to retrieve row only if other rows have same column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a MySQL query that will retrieve a row only if it has the same value for 2 columns with other rows that share the same group. To be specific, the name of only one of the rows must be returned if multiple rows that have the same group all have status = 'S' and active = 1. Otherwise, the name should not be returned.

example db

```
id         name       status   active   group
-----      ------     ------   ------   -----
1          Alpha        S         1      A
2          Bravo        S         0      A
3          Charlie      S         1      B
4          Delta        F         1      B
5          Echo         S         1      C
6          Foxtrot      S         1      C 
7          Golf         S         1      C
```

expected result

```
name     
------  
Echo/FoxTrot/Golf (Either one is fine)
```

Comment: your desire is not clear, Alpha and Charlie also have same status and active values

Comment: They do not belong to the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery will return all groups that have values other than 'S' for status OR 1 for active.
Then query only the groups that are not in this condition.
Since you don't mind which of the names will be returned you can use MIN function.

```
SELECT MIN(name) 
FROM table
WHERE group NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT group FROM table WHERE (status != 'S' OR active != 1))
GROUP BY group
```

Another solution using HAVING instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT MIN(name) 
FROM table
GROUP BY group
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS != 'S' OR ACTIVE != 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind all the names put together, then it can be done with a simple query. You will see comma separated names.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM Table
WHERE active = 1
GROUP BY group
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1;
```